# Send data to iframe using get in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, iframe

i create one button in html

```
<input type="button"  value="Simulate" class="submit_btn"  id="stimulate" />
```

and use jquery onclick event and create iframe , i want to send lat, long and title to iframe and create dynamic map but i send **get 10 % discount** as a subtitle , i get following error

```
GET http://domain name/name of controller/name of function/57.643821505750964/12.180534033203116//get%2010%%20discount 400 (Bad Request)



$("#stimulate").click(function() {
var ad_lng = document.getElementById("longclicked").value;
var ad_subtitle = document.getElementById("ad_subtitle").value;
var ad_lat = document.getElementById("latclicked").value;

$('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe id="iframe" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/frame_stimulator/'+ad_lat+'/'+ad_lng+'/'+ad_subtitle+'" width="700" height="550" scrolling="no"  frameborder="0"></iframe>');
}
```

how can i send data to iframe . i dont want to use form and send data by post method..
without using form i can post data to iframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass them in the query string:

```
var ad_lng = encodeURIComponent( document.getElementById("longclicked").value );
var ad_subtitle = encodeURIComponent( document.getElementById("ad_subtitle").value );
var ad_lat = encodeURIComponent( document.getElementById("latclicked").value );

$('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe id="iframe" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/frame_stimulator?ad_lat='+ad_lat+'&ad_lng='+ad_lng+'&ad_subtitle='+ad_subtitle+'" width="700" height="550" scrolling="no"  frameborder="0"></iframe>');
```

In codeigniter code you would retrieve them:

```
$lat = $this->input->get("ad_lat");
$lng = $this->input->get("ad_lng");
$subtitle = $this->input->get("ad_subtitle");
```

Comment: public function frame_stimulator()
 {
 
  $data['lat']=$this->input->get("ad_lat");
  $data['lon']=$this->input->get("ad_lng");
  $data['address']=$$this->input->get("ad_subtitle");
}  it gives 500 internal server error

Comment: @rash111 why do you have `$$this->input->get`? Why 2 dollars? Try it with only one: `public function frame_stimulator() {
 $data['lat'] = $this->input->get("ad_lat");
 $data['lon'] = $this->input->get("ad_lng");
 $data['address'] = $this->input->get("ad_subtitle"); 
} `

Comment: sorry brother and thanks it is working, but i have another question when i change lat, long in input field and again click on simulate button it show previous lat , long map.. why this is happen

Comment: public function frame_stimulator()
 {
 
  $data['lat']=$this->input->get("ad_lat");
  $data['lon']=$this->input->get("ad_lng");
  $data['address']=$this->input->get("ad_subtitle");
  $this->load->view('frame_stimulator',$data);
 }
here i accept data and pass to view

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() 
  {
    var stateCollege = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat ?>, <?php echo $lon ?>);
    var myOptions = 
    {
      zoom: 11,
      center: stateCollege,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: stateCollege,
   map: map
  });
 
 
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()" style="margin:0px;">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:450px; height:250px"></div>
</body>

Comment: @rash111 just the relevant javascript code only, you can delete those comments. The comments you just made, they are not relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke a javascript function in an iframe from the parent/container page. So if you script a function in the iframe page that takes data as a parameter, then you can invoke it from the main page that contains iframe.

Check this: [Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page)

Comment: this is only possible, if both parent and iframe originate from the same domain.

Comment: @Christoph Absolutely true. I saw `base_url()` in `iframe src` and didn't want to mention that.